# FusionCharts : use '...' at the end of axisName

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

I've come here after so many hours of research. And in vain.

`axisnames autoadjust` in two lines or more depending on the width. Here's is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s7t8F/1372/) of it

I want it to end with '...' as it does with labels.

When I use `"useEllipsesWhenOverflow" : "1"` it works sometimes in firefox but does not have the same behavior in chrome.

at JSFiddle I don't think you could replicate the same thing unless you run it from local.

So how can I disable the adjust or use '...' at the end of axisNames ?
Any help or a path would be appreciated.

Best regards.

Comment: Using ellipses is the last option when text can not be accommodated in any possible ways. The attribute `useEllipsesWhenOverflow` is applicable to data labels (x axis labels) and not on axis name. Ellipses for axis name will appear automatically when text can not be shown completely. If any text is defined, FusionCharts assumes it is highly important to establish the context of the chart, specially for the axis name, caption, sub-caption.

Comment: Well, it does appear automatically only for firefox but for chrome it's adjusted in two lines and I don't want that behavior at all.

Comment: Why do you want to show text that is not so important?

Comment: In my case, it is important. (you know, the customer and his needs ...)

Comment: I understand. But unfortunately not possible. :(

Comment: :(, Thank you for your replies ^_^